# 'cope with' means 'put up with'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence-construction, idioms, synonyms

Nobody knows how the Indian cricket team is going to ***cope with*** the difficult and seamer-friendly wickets in Australia.

Choose the option which is closest in meaning to the ***bold-italic*** phrase in the above sentence.

1. put up with
2. put in with
3. put down to
4. put up against

---

My attempt :

- *put up with:* tolerate
- *put in with:* to partner with
- *put down to:* attribute
- *put up against:* to place someone into competition with someone else

‘cope with’ means 'put up with'?

Can you explain in formal way, please?

Comment: Generally, questions that are just asking whether you've come to the right conclusion are a bit awkward for ELL; if you're right, there's no more to say. If you just need a sanity check, [chat] might be better for you. Otherwise, splitting off your reasoning into a self-answer to explain what you think and why would probably work better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Put up with** and **cope with** are not exactly interchangeable.

To **cope with** is to take into account an adverse situation and overcome it, to **deal with it**.

To **put up with** *something* is merely to **tolerate it** but not necessarily to overcome it.

Your passage is wondering how the Indian cricket team will deal with spinners when playing Australia.  Given your choices **put up with** would be the best choice, however **overcome** would be a better substitute for **cope with**.